# Why PHP/Curl doesn't keep the cookie data for the session

Tags: php, session, curl, cookies

I am learning PHP Curl with [Webbots, Spiders, and Screen Scrapers, 2nd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781593273972.do). The chapter about cookie authentication shows this code:

```
# Define target page 
$target = "http://www.WebbotsSpidersScreenScrapers.com/cookie_authentication/index.php";
# Define the login form data
$form_data="enter=Enter&username=webbot&password=sp1der3";
# Create the PHP/CURL session
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target); // Define target site
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // Return page in string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt"); // Tell PHP/CURL where to write cookies
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt"); // Tell PHP/CURL which cookies to send
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $form_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); // Follow redirects
# Execute the PHP/CURL session and echo the downloaded page
$page = curl_exec($ch);
echo $page; 
# Close the PHP/CURL session
curl_close($ch);
```

when I get log in the test website using the web browser, I get the message "Your login is good for another 3600 seconds" and whenever I reload the page I see the time goes down (which is a completely normal behaviour since the server recognize the session number and handle everything that goes with it, including the time before). Now when I run the example code (listed above), the authenticate value keeps changing every time I run the script. My guess is because of the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");` instruction. But here is the think: even if I comment that line which by the way prevent the script to change the cookie, The script still get the "same" response from the server (the login is still good for 3600 - 3599 secs). Can this be solved in some way?

Comment: Does it actually write anything inside cookies.txt?

Comment: @LauriOrgla yes it does `www.WebbotsSpidersScreenScrapers.com FALSE /cookie_authentication/ FALSE 0 authenticate 1410458823`. The last value changes whenever I run the script if the cookiejar instruction is uncommented.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem, is that you are not using cookie sessions with curl.

Try setting cookie sessions like that:

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
```

Working example:

```
function getSessionTime($answer) {

    $parts      = explode('<font color="red">', $answer);
    $bottomPart = $parts[1];
    $parts      = explode('</font>', $bottomPart);
    $result     = $parts[0];

    return $result;
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.WebbotsSpidersScreenScrapers.com/cookie_authentication/index.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "enter=Enter&username=webbot&password=sp1der3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie-name'); //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/var/www/ip4.x/file/tmp'); //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts

echo getSessionTime(curl_exec($ch));
sleep(1);
echo getSessionTime(curl_exec($ch));
sleep(1);
echo getSessionTime(curl_exec($ch));
sleep(1);
echo getSessionTime(curl_exec($ch));
sleep(1);
echo getSessionTime(curl_exec($ch));
sleep(1);
echo getSessionTime(curl_exec($ch));
```

Output:

```
<br>
Your login is good for another 3600 seconds
<br>
Your login is good for another 3599 seconds
<br>
Your login is good for another 3597 seconds
<br>
Your login is good for another 3596 seconds
<br>
Your login is good for another 3595 seconds
<br>
Your login is good for another 3594 seconds
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to make a difference. However, it looks like as long as the script is running (with or without the COOKIESESSION) the script uses normal behaviour (I just added a `sleep()` instruction and recall `$page = curl_exec($ch); echo $page; ` after that and the new response definitely shows that time has elapsed. but what I want is for it to work even if I stop the script and re-run it again.

Comment: Actually you must make a check, if checks if the cookie file exists. You are not supposed to create a new cookie if u run ur script again. Because new cookie = new session.

Comment: As I said on the original question, commenting the COOKIEJAR instruction (on the re-run) doesn't make the session stick. I also tried commenting The COOKIEJAR instruction and replace it with COOKIESESSION instruction. No change so far: If the script stops running and I run it again it still gives me 3600 sec. Adding a `if (!file_exists("cookies.txt")){}` doesn't make a difference either (even if I do understand the need for it).